# User input always true using the .is_ok functions

Tags: rust, user-input

How can I read from the console and avoid crashing if the user presses enter without entering anything?

```
let mut objectnumber = String::new();
println!("mennyi súlyt szeretnél megnézni? 3.=255 int");
if io::stdin().read_line(&mut objectnumber).is_ok() {
   println!("{}csdcds", objectnumber);
}

//panic!("{}",objectnumber.len());
if objectnumber.len() < 3 {
   let localrandnum: u8 = thread_rng().gen_range(0..=255);
   println!("miután nem adtál meg semmit sem ezért {localrandnum}.at írtam be neked");
   objectnumber = localrandnum.to_string();
}
let objectnumber: u8 = objectnumber.trim().parse::<u8>().expect("null");
```

This is working but I don't think it should be done like this in Rust.
I don't know why is it ok even on empty line while the parse is talking about it being empty.

Comment: Why won't it be ok? Nothing has failed.

Comment: `is_ok` detects *errors*, not content. That is, `is_ok` on `read_line` will return false is the stdin stream was closed suddenly or was otherwise rendered inoperable (probably due to things outside your program's control). If you're on a typical Unix-like system, you can close stdin by hitting CTRL+D in your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes I made:

- `read_line` returns a `Result` indicating whether or not there was an error reading from `stdin`. Usually this only happens in very specific circumstances, so let's just `unwrap` this for now.
- `objectnumber.len()` gives you the length of the string, not its content. To check its content for `< 3`, we need to `parse()` it to a `u8` first.
- Don't `expect` the `parse`, because this one depends on user input. Do a proper error handling instead. This is the point that will tell you if the number is >255, <0 or something else entirely. Let's for now just default to '0', because it will then get caught by the `< 3`.
- Don't convert the number you generated with the `thread_rng` to a `String`; instead, write it to `objectnumber` directly. There is no point in converting it to a String and back.

```
use std::io;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut objectnumber = String::new();
    println!("mennyi súlyt szeretnél megnézni? 3.=255 int");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut objectnumber)
        .expect("Unable to read from stdin!");

    // Convert from String to u8
    let mut objectnumber: u8 = objectnumber.trim().parse::<u8>().unwrap_or(0);

    if objectnumber < 3 {
        objectnumber = thread_rng().gen_range(0..=255);
        println!("miután nem adtál meg semmit sem ezért {objectnumber}.at írtam be neked");
    }

    println!("objectnumber: {}", objectnumber);
}
```

```
mennyi súlyt szeretnél megnézni? 3.=255 int
33
objectnumber: 33
```

```
mennyi súlyt szeretnél megnézni? 3.=255 int
1
miután nem adtál meg semmit sem ezért 191.at írtam be neked
objectnumber: 191
```